# How does one get the HTML attributes from a wicket componet?

Tags: wicket

I can't find a method that allows me to pull the attributes from a component, or better, one specific attribute. Here is an example:

1. I have two text areas (components).
2. Both are expandable
3. While typing in the first one, it auto expands with Ajax, and the height grows.
4. I get the height attribute from the first text area
5. I set the height of the second text area to height I have got from the first one.

   ```
    public class HomePage extends WebPage {

    TextArea t = new TextArea("m", "hey");;

   TextArea t2 = new TextArea("m2",
       "this is a label with label ones attributes added");

   public HomePage() {

   add(t.add(new AttributeModifier("height", "100;")));


   add(t2.add(HERE ADD THE ATTRIBUE HEIGHT FROM LABEL);

   }
   ```

Comment: What you want to achieve on the UI? Do you want to expand the second `textarea` then first one grows while typing?

Comment: So I type the first one and the height grows from 100 to 150. I get the final height attribute (150) and set the second textarea height to 150.

Comment: how do you get the final height? via js or via behavior? because if you just do it with js, you can apply a jquery script to alter the style of the second textarea and that's it

Comment: I want to get it via the attributes, not from a js script

Comment: ok so when you type, a behavior is called and inside this behavior you set the textarea1's height. do you add it to ajaxrequesttarget in order to take the changes? remember that inside an ajax behavior you have to add the components you want to update (and also set outputmarkupid to true when initialized)

Comment: for expanding the `<textarea>` you use the jquery plugin or a similar one i told you about in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424251/growable-text-area-in-wicket

Comment: The above is just an example, the component I am working on has serveral different Ajax behaviors, which will cause differnet effects on the textarea, what i really just need is a way to take the height attribute from the textarea and set it to another text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution uses JavaScript for the height modification. t1 is the one that by typing is growing, t2 is the one that's height is being adjusted. Clean and nice i think.

```
private TextArea textarea1() {
    TextArea t1 = new TextArea("t1", Model.of("t1"));
    final String js = "document.getElementById('%s').style.height = document.getElementById('%s').style.height;";
    t1.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.appendJavaScript(String.format(js, textarea2.getMarkupId(), textarea1.getMarkupId()));
        }
    });
    t1.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    return t1;
}

private TextArea textarea2() {
    TextArea t2 = new TextArea("t2", Model.of("t2"));
    t2.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    return t2;
}
```

Earlier in your page/panel class declare private fields and assign them the two textarea's

```
private Textarea textarea1;
private Textarea textarea2;
```

in ctor:

```
textarea1 = textarea1();
textarea2 = textarea2();
add(textarea1);
add(textarea2);
```

Comment: Beautiful, I really like what you've done there, it's got me thinking in a different (better) way.

Comment: I've just tried this but I think something might be missing. In eclipse, in on update the textarea2 is in error, it says I need to create a local variable. So I'm not sure how textarea2 will update?

Comment: Yes, declare fields in your class private TextArea textarea1, textarea2. Normally on StackOverflow you dont get code ready to copy paste and compile, just an idea how it should be done. It requires some work in integration into your code.